# How to use directly injected mappers in jersey along with spring

Tags: spring, jersey, jax-rs, mybatis

I'm new to Spring/MyBatis area.

I have a question about software stacks and usages that I'm working on. I'm currently trying to work with following stacks.

```
JAX-RS   (+ org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring3)
Spring   (+ org:mybatis:mybatis-spring)
MyBatis3
```

My mappers, services, and resources look like this.

```java
public interface MyMapper { // MyBatis Mapper
    void doSomething();
    void doSomethingElse();
}

@Service
public class MyService { // Spring Service
    @Autowired private MyMapper myMapper;
    @Autowired private YourMapper yourMapper;
    public void doSomething() {
        myMapper.doSomething();
        yourMapper.doSomething();
    }
}

@Path("/my")
public class MyResource { // JAX-RS Resource
    @Authwired
    private MyService myService;
    // Now I can call MyService#doSomething
    // How can I call MyMapper#doSomethingElse?
}
```

Is there any way to inject MyBatis mappers or `SqlSession` directly into JAX-RS resources? If yes, what kind of issues should I concern? Say, transaction or SqlSession management?

You know, just like when we inject `@PersistenceUnit EntityManagerFactory`.

Thanks.